# IndexError only when not hardcoding values

Tags: python

Why on earth do I keep getting this error? I can't work it out.

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self):
        self.connect = ""
        self.accept = ""
        self.ipport = ""
        self.customer = ""
        self.iptablestext = open('iptables', 'rb')
    def client(self):
        with open('stunnel.conf', 'rb') as stunnel:
            for line in stunnel:
                if line.startswith('[customer-'):
                    self.customer = (line.split('-')[1].split('-')[0].strip())
                elif line.startswith('accept'):
                    self.accept = (line.split(" = ")[1].strip())
                    MyParser.ip_collector(self.accept)
                elif line.startswith('connect'):
                    self.connect = (line.split(" = ")[1].strip())
                    MyParser.write_to_file()
    def write_to_file(self):
        with open('customer.yml', 'a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(self.customer + ":" + "\n  accept: " + self.accept + "\n  connect: " + self.connect + "\n  ipaddr: " + self.ipport + "\n")
            myfile.close()
    def ip_collector(self, acceptport):
        with open('iptables', 'rb') as iptables:
            for line in iptables:
                if self.accept in line:
                    self.ipport = (line.split(' -s ')[1].split(' -p ')[0].strip())
```

I am trying to pass the 'self.accept' value in to the ip_collector function so that I can search a seperate file for the ip port for each client. But I can't seem to work out why every time I run it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parserclient.py", line 37, in <module>
    MyParser.clear_output(), MyParser.client()
  File "./parserclient.py", line 18, in client
    MyParser.ip_collector(self.accept)
  File "./parserclient.py", line 30, in ip_collector
    self.ipport = (line.split(' -s ')[1].split(' -p ')[0].strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It works fine when I hard code an accept port in to the ip collectors function.

Comment: hi, where do you use acceptport ?

Comment: What value has the `line` variable just before you attempt `self.ipport = ...`?

Comment: That is an example of what a line in iptables looks like

Comment: -A INPUT -s 81.168.12.249/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 32501 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Well for this one you shouldn't get an error, but for the one you posted before, but deleted again, the line could not be split by `' -s '`, so trying to access the second (`[1]`) item would result in an index error.